# Coverage doesn't work in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, devtools

I'm trying to use Coverage in Chrome Dev Tools.
I did try **Ctrl+Shift+P > Show Coverage** (drawer) and **More Tools > Coverage** but nothing happens. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that there was a conflict between Chrome and Adobe Illustrator.

I hadn't noticed at first, but Illustrator, which was open in the background, had "gone black". I tried again restarting the computer and both programs. I managed to use Coverage in Dev Tools but after about twenty minutes Illustrator froze again and Chrome started behaving strangely (For example hover was not working). I will have to contact Adobe regarding this issue.